# c and c++ mixed

Tags: c++, c, interface, mixing

I need to call cpp method from c file.
I have written this interface for that..

cpp file

```
extern "C" void C_Test(int p){
      Class::CPP_Test(p);
}
```

c file

```
extern void C_Test(int p);


void C_Function(){
   C_Test(10); //error
}
```

I get error in c file **"undefined reference to C_Test(int)"**

any idea whats wrong?

Comment: You need to show information about how this is compiled and linked.

Comment: You're not linking everything.

Comment: I am using C++ compiler for both types of files. Without "C" it works!! Also without extern "c" it works!

Comment: @Meloun, because your mangling the same.  Your extern "C" needs to be in the .hpp where the function is declared and in the .cpp file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using C++ compiler for both types of files. 
Without "C" it works!! Also without extern "c" it works!

Comment: That's just confusing. You said in your question that you need to call a C++ function from C file, i.e. you are using C and C++ compilers. Now you are saying that you only use C++ compiler. What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

You must declare extern only for function prototype, and ensure to link correctly. In addiction to this, CPP_Test(p) must be a static member of Class, otherwise your code does not work. At last, extern "C" must enclose in brackets its content, more like

```
extern "C"
{
  void C_Test(int p)
  {
    Class::CPP_Test(p);
  }
}
```

Tell us if this works.

Answer (score 1):

Are you compiling both with a C++ compiler?  C++ compilers may compile a C-source file as C++, in which case it will perform name mangling, so you need to be sure to compile the C source file with a C compiler.

Comment: I've seen them mangle and add prefix (I think Visual Studio possibly from memory, or maybe Borland), so even if you extern "C" your function may be _C_Test(int).  Look at your settings.  Also check your  map file to see what symbols are being exported.